# tensor flow on gpu is slow, plus more questions

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision

I'm trying to do people detection using tensorflow.

Here is a video of what I came up for

https://youtu.be/93XOujVi-1U

My questions.
1. I run the tensorflow on GPU 1050ti nvidia, and it's extremly slow
2. The detection still flickers, but thanks to kalman filter that I did it does keep consistent IDs, but how can I make the detection smooth and keeps detecting without flickering?

Here is the detection code that I'm using

```
def get_localization(self, image, visual=False):

        """Determines the locations of the cars in the image
        Args:
            image: camera image
        Returns:
            list of bounding boxes: coordinates [y_up, x_left, y_down, x_right]
        """
        category_index = {1: {'id': 1, 'name': u'person'},
                          2: {'id': 2, 'name': u'bicycle'},
                          3: {'id': 3, 'name': u'car'},
                          4: {'id': 4, 'name': u'motorcycle'},
                          5: {'id': 5, 'name': u'airplane'},
                          6: {'id': 6, 'name': u'bus'},
                          7: {'id': 7, 'name': u'train'},
                          8: {'id': 8, 'name': u'truck'},
                          9: {'id': 9, 'name': u'boat'},
                          10: {'id': 10, 'name': u'traffic light'},
                          11: {'id': 11, 'name': u'fire hydrant'},
                          13: {'id': 13, 'name': u'stop sign'},
                          14: {'id': 14, 'name': u'parking meter'}}

        with self.detection_graph.as_default():
            image_expanded = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
            (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = self.sess.run(
                [self.boxes, self.scores, self.classes, self.num_detections],
                feed_dict={self.image_tensor: image_expanded})

            if visual == True:
                vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
                    image,
                    np.squeeze(boxes),
                    np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
                    np.squeeze(scores),
                    category_index,
                    use_normalized_coordinates=True, min_score_thresh=.4,
                    line_thickness=3)

                plt.figure(figsize=(9, 6))
                plt.imshow(image)
                plt.show()

            boxes = np.squeeze(boxes)
            classes = np.squeeze(classes)
            scores = np.squeeze(scores)

            cls = classes.tolist()

            # The ID for car in COCO data set is 3
            idx_vec = [i for i, v in enumerate(cls) if ((v == 1) or (v == 3) or (v == 2)or (v == 4)or (v == 8)and (scores[i] > 0.6))]

            if len(idx_vec) == 0:
                print('no detection!')
                self.car_boxes = []
            else:
                tmp_car_boxes = []
                for idx in idx_vec:
                    dim = image.shape[0:2]
                    box = self.box_normal_to_pixel(boxes[idx], dim, scores[idx])
                    box_h = box[2] - box[0]
                    box_w = box[3] - box[1]
                    ratio = box_h / (box_w + 0.01)

                    if ((ratio < 0.8 or ratio > 0.8) and (box_h > 20) and (box_w > 20)):
                        tmp_car_boxes.append(box)
                        #print(box, ', confidence: ', scores[idx], 'ratio:', ratio)

                    #else:
                        #print('wrong ratio or wrong size, ', box, ', confidence: ', scores[idx], 'ratio:', ratio)

                self.car_boxes = tmp_car_boxes

        return self.car_boxes
```

Comment: How do you feed your data in? (What is the type of „image“)

Comment: The image is an RGB image, and I get it from opencv cv2 video capture, as the input is a video

Answer (score 0):

One of the Problems is, that you are using feed dicts in your input pipeline which is a very inefficient thing to do. You basically go from OpenCV C++ to Python to TensorFlow C++ which kills a lot of performance and bottle necks your GPU.

Unfortunately I have no straight answer on how to solve this problem in TensorFlow in combination with OpenCV. I have been using Nvidias TensorRT in the past and it works really good. The basic approach with this Framework would be:

1. Train model in TensorFlow
2. Freeze graph in TensorFlow
3. convert Modell to TensorRT engine
4. Load TensorRT engine and run inference

During this process you can also „shave off“ some of the unnecessary parts of your model to improve performance.

Another approach is shown in this [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/real-time-and-video-processing-object-detection-using-tensorflow-opencv-and-docker-2be1694726e5). He is using some kind of multithreaded multi process mixture to fetch the video data!